# desktop monitor setup - emulate laptop

Tags: display

Is there a way a monitor can be tilted all the way down like a laptop monitor does when you close the lid.  Due to space, the computer display may be required to not take more than 4-5 inches of vertical space when not working.

I could put the monitor under the table when not working, but that could be a hassle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure I understand the question correctly. But if you just want to be able to adjust the stand angle then you just need a stand which can work at these angles. Most monitors however can just be tilted a couple of degrees.

Most screens come with standardized mount locations called VESA100. This allows such screens to be mounted to any standard VESA100 stand. Maybe you could just buy a wall-mount with VESA100-compatible mount in order to achieve the tilt level you need.